# PayPal error "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later"

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

With the recent PayPal update our site PayPal payment stopped working

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2067

I'm sending these information to the PayPal

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&business=payment%40mysite.com&no_note=1&currency_code=HKD&charset=UTF-8&rm=1&upload=1&return=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fcheckout%2Forder-received%2F22572%3Fkey%3Dwc_order_590c17c6bfdfa%26%23038%3Butm_nooverride%3D1&cancel_return=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fcart%2F%3Fcancel_order%3Dtrue%26%23038%3Border%3Dwc_order_590c17c6bfdfa%26%23038%3Border_id%3D22572%26%23038%3Bredirect%26%23038%3B_wpnonce%3Dcede2c20d5&page_style=&paymentaction=sale&bn=WooThemes_Cart&invoice=SIM-22572&custom=a%3A2%3A{i%3A0%3Bi%3A22572%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A22%3A"wc_order_590c17c6bfdfa"%3B}&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fwc-api%2FWC_Gateway_Paypal%2F&first_name=sampth&last_name=bandara&company=test&address1=suneth2%40gmail.com&address2=&city=test&state=0010&zip=&country=AE&email=suneth2%40gmail.com&night_phone_b=test&day_phone_b=test&no_shipping=1&tax_cart=0&item_name_1=%E8%91%A1%E8%90%84%E7%89%99%E4%B8%8A%E7%B6%B2SIM%E5%8D%A1+(+%E6%97%A5%E6%95%B8%3A+10%E6%97%A5+(500MB)+)&quantity_1=1&amount_1=700
```

But PayPal redirects it to

```
https://www.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart/error?flowlogging_id=77d571fcb7ab&code=BAD_INPUT_ERROR&mfid=1493964887581_77d571fcb7ab
```

and says

> Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.

What input should I change to work this payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it fixed, I used POST data instead of use GET method

Comment: Hi how did you send POST data instead of GET? are you using the standard paypal integrated with woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

**This is a temporary error**

This is a temporary error from paypal. Please wait for some time and it will automatically get fixed. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is from the PayPal side.
So wait for a time.
if it is not solved then remove cookies and cache from your browser then check.